# invoking curried function without passing another argument

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying

I have a simple function that takes one argument

```
fn = function(argument) {console.log(argument)}
```

In `setInterval`, I want to call the function and pass an external variable:

```
argument = 1
setInterval(<MY FUNCTION WITH ACCESS TO ARGUMENT>, 1000)
```

I realize that I could do it with a higher-order function, i.e.

```
fn = function(argument) {
  function () {
    console.log(argument)
  }
}
argument = 1
setInterval(fn(argument), 1000)
```

And this does work, but I want to know if it can be done with `curry`.

I've tried:

```
fn = _.curry(fn)("foo")
// since the function takes only one argument,
// here it is invoked and no longer can be
// passed as a function to setInterval

fn = _.curry(fn, 2)("foo")
// setting the arity to 2 makes it so the function
// isn't invoked. But setInterval does not pass
// the additional argument and so it never ends
// up getting invoked.
```

I feel like there is something I'm missing with these curry examples. Am I, or will curry not help here?

Comment: Why not use `fn.bind(this, argument)`?

Comment: @trincot exactly! Why even bother with third-party libraries for built-in language capabilities?

Comment: cool, so bind is like curry but allows invoking without an additional argument. seems perfect.

Comment: OK, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: What `curry` function are you using there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed lodash `_.curry` seems not suitable for your use-case.

But you can use the vanilla JavaScript [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) for this:

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.
>
> #### Syntax
>
> ```
> fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
> ```

In your case your code would look like this:

```
fn = function(argument) {console.log(argument)}

var argument = 1
setInterval(fn.bind(this, argument), 1000)
```

#### Lodash alternative

If you really want to do it the lodash way, the equivalant of `fn.bind(thisArg, ...args)` is `_.bind(fn, thisArg, ...args)`. And if you are not interested in setting the `this` reference, then you can save one argument with [`_.partial(fn, ...args)`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2#partial):

> Creates a function that invokes **func** with **partials** prepended to the arguments it receives. This method is like [`_.bind`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2#bind) except it does not alter the `this` binding.

Comment: Lodash's `partial` should do